# iPhone App for Displaying Email on a Locked Screen with Exchange Support

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation

I have an app, "mail notifier" that sends notifications to my phone when I get a new email, it does not support Exchange though.

Is there an app that is similar that does support exchange, maybe an app that does 'local' notifications so there is not a reoccurring cost?

Comment: The notification manager is getting a total overhaul for iOS 5 - so head to http://www.apple.com/ios/ios5/features.html#notification and click on the "lock screen" to see what is planned. It will be built in so no need for forwarding, a separate account, etc...

Comment: You are correct, a long time coming though.

Comment: Just hope the server doesn't force you to disable that feature.

Comment: @bmike I can see it being a security risk having it displayed on the front of the iPhone, the texting has that problem now...

Comment: Companies will fail security audits if internal mail contents is displayed on a locked computer. If you're the boss, you can make those calls. General corporate policy would clearly restrict this as the default behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 5 has added this feature to operating system, and no app is needed to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

### [LockInfo](http://david.ashman.com/lockinfo/)

> LockInfo gives you access to your information where you need it, when you need it. You can **view your new emails, upcoming calendar events, unread SMSs, missed calls and much more on your lockscreen**, SpringBoard or even within any application on your iPhone, iPod Touch or iPad.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [**Boxcar**](http://boxcar.io).

You'll have to trust them, though, since the way to get visual notification for new mail is to forward all your mail to a @boxcar.io address generated only for your account.

Then, everytime you'll get a mail, it will be forwarded to your Boxcar address and pushed to your iPhone.